# QB64: "Duplicate Definition" error when using variable type suffixes with '$DYNAMIC

Tags: qbasic, qb64

Why is it, in QB64, that

```
'$dynamic
x&(5) = x&(5) + 1
x&(5) = x&(5) + 1
x&(5) = x&(5) + 1
x&(5) = x&(5) + 1
x&(5) = x&(5) + 1
```

works fine, while

```
    '$dynamic
for g = 1 to 5
    x&(5) = x&(5) + 1
next g
```

gives a "duplicate definition" error at `x&(5) = x&(5) + 1`?

Comment: I tried the code, including a print statement in there to verify, and I'm not getting this error.  The issue is in QB64?

Comment: Also in QB64 I don't verify the issue you describe.